# Office 365 API that is not connected to Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, api, office365, azure-active-directory

I want to know one thing very clear.
I need to get all users of Office 365 using `C#`.
For that, there are lots of `api` but all of them are connected with Azure Active Directory. (For eg. `Graph api` which is also connected to Azure )

But I want `api` that is not connected with Azure Active Directory to get all users of Office 365.

Is there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access Office 365 users without accessing Azure Active Directory. Office 365 by default uses Azure AD in the back end to manage users.

Please see this article for a more detailed explanation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/understanding-office-365-identity-and-azure-active-directory-06a189e7-5ec6-4af2-94bf-a22ea225a7a9